# How can i get the image as in the preview size of TextureView in camera 2

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am learning camera 2 API using google sample code [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) in that i have changed the width and height of `AutoFitTextureView` to 200 dp and when i capture the picture then i seeing that picture has more focused area than the preview size.

So How can i get the image as in the preview?

Comment: What do you mean when you asking how can I get the image as in the preview?. Are you talking about that you want a cropped image, or do you want to get the camera whole image based on imageReader? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the image to be cropped the same way as your preview, which is what I think you are asking, you can use the the SCALER_CROP_REGION which is a field of the Camera2 API CaptureRequest class.

More information is available here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#SCALER_CROP_REGION